# Как сделать открывающуюся кнопку с текстом внутри?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пока что додумался только до этого, но если сделать их несколько и разместить в разных местах станицы, они почему то открываются то влево, то вправо.

```js
function openButton(el) {

  var firstChild = el.firstChild;
  var lastChild = el.lastChild;

  el.classList.toggle("expand");

  if (lastChild.style.display === "none") {
    lastChild.style.display = "inline";
    firstChild.style.float = "left";

  } else {
    lastChild.style.display = "none";
    firstChild.style.float = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.button1.expand,
.button2.expand {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.button1 {
  border: 1px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(56, 119, 238, 0.8);
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button1" id="item1" onclick="openButton(this);"><span class="icon">+</span><span style="display: none;">Текст</span></button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button class="button2" id="item2" onclick="openButton(this);"><span class="icon">+</span><span style="display: none;">Текст</span></button>
</div>
```

Предложения как лучше сделать?

Comment: Открытие "в разные стороны" обусловлены тем что элемент как-то должен поместиться "в потоке" при увеличении размеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Предложения как лучше сделать?

Начать можно с таких модернизаций...

Но и от `+` в контенте желательно избавиться, используя псевдоклассы `:before` или `:after`. Но там с размерами и центрированием нужно будет "поиграться"...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.mybtn').forEach(o => o.addEventListener('click', openButton))
function openButton() {
  this.classList.toggle("expand");
}
```

```css
.mybtn.expand {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.mybtn > :last-child {
  display: none;
}
.mybtn.expand > :last-child {
  display: inline;
}
.mybtn > :first-child {
  float: none;
}
.mybtn.expand > :first-child {
  float: left;
}

.button1 {
  border: 1px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(56, 119, 238, 0.8);
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="mybtn button1" id="item1"><span class="icon">+</span><span>Текст</span></button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button class="mybtn button2" id="item2"><span class="icon">+</span><span>Текст</span></button>
</div>
```